# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'float'

Tags: python, dictionary

Line 26 of this code is giving me error and I haven't been able to fix it. Please help me figure it out.
This is the line:
`path[road]['distance_from_start'] = path.get(road, {}).get('distance_from_start') + path.get(road, {}).get('distance_to_neighbor')` 
What it is supposed to find is the shortest path between a starting point and destination goal in a map with multiple intermediary stops in between.

```
import math
def my_function(M, start, goal):
    frontier = set([start])
    expanded = set()
    chosen = start
    chosen_coordinates = M.intersections[chosen]
    goal_coordinates = M.intersections[goal]
    roads_to_choose = M.roads[chosen]
    path = {}
    while frontier != set():
        if chosen != goal:
            for road in roads_to_choose:
                if road not in expanded:
                    frontier.add(road)
                    path[road] = {}
                    path[road]['coordinate'] = {}
                    path[road]['roads'] = {}
                    path[road]['distance_to_goal'] = {}
                    path[road]['distance_to_neighbor'] = {}
                    path[road]['distance_from_start'] = {}
                    path[road]['g_plus_h'] = {}
                    path[road]['path_list'] = {}
                    path[road]['coordinate'] = M.intersections[road]
                    path[road]['roads'] = M.roads[road]
                    path[road]['distance_to_neighbor'] = math.sqrt(((M.intersections[road][0]-chosen_coordinates[0])**2) + ((M.intersections[road][1]-chosen_coordinates[1])**2))
                    path[road]['distance_from_start'] = path.get(road, {}).get('distance_from_start') + path.get(road, {}).get('distance_to_neighbor')
                    path[road]['distance_to_goal'] = math.sqrt(((goal_coordinates[0]-M.intersections[road][0])**2) + ((goal_coordinates[1]-M.intersections[road][1])**2))
                    path[road]['g_plus_h'] = path[road]['distance_from_start'] + path[road]['distance_to_goal']
                    path[road]['path_list'] = path[chosen]['path_list'].append(road)
            frontier.remove(chosen)
            expanded.add(chosen)
            if x not in expanded:
                chosen = min(path.keys(), key=lambda x:path[x]['g_plus_h'])
                path[road]['distance_from_start'] = path.get(chosen, {}).get('distance_from_start')
        else:
            print("Short path called")  
            return path[goal]['path_list']
```

Comment: I can't count to 26. Which line is it.

Comment: path[road]['distance_from_start'] = path.get(road, {}).get('distance_from_start') + path.get(road, {}).get('distance_to_neighbor')

Comment: You initialise it as `path[road]['distance_from_start'] = {}`, which is a dict. Just as the error message tells you, you are adding a dictionary and a number, which is not a valid operation.

Comment: I see. I had to initialize it and the others as dict to create nested dictionaries but once I put the values in there I want to retrieve them to add them to other values. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add two dictionary items like this:

```
x={}
y={}
z = x+ y
```

This is the wrong way to that , thats why you are getting this error. What exactly you want to do with those two dictonary , your result depends on that. If you want to merge them then try this:

In Python 3.5 or greater, :

```
z = {**x, **y}
```

In Python 2, (or 3.4 or lower) write a function:

```
def merge(x, y):
    z = x.copy()   
    z.update(y)   
    return z
z = merge(x, y)
```

By looking at your code,your problem can be solved by changing the assignments in the beginning , change

```
path[road]['distance_to_neighbor'] = 0
path[road]['distance_from_start'] = 0
```

Then you will able to get your results.